# Is updating an object nested inside an array via JsonPatchDocument possible?

Tags: json, rest, .net-core, json-patch

I'm using Microsoft.AspNetCore.JsonPatch V2.1.1.

I have an object structure like this:

```
{
  "key" : "value",
  "nested" : [
    { "key" : "value" }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to update the key in the nested object within the array:

```
[
    {"op" : "replace", "path" : "/nested/0/key", "value" : "test" }
]
```

But I get this exception:

> JsonPatchException: The target location specified by path segment '0' was not found.

Do I have to explicitly make an endpoint for the inner object with its own PATCH method?